# Testing in tomcat when it is running multiple applications

Tags: java, tomcat

I am new to java. I am currently working on a web application where tomcat has to load about 24 web applications for the whole thing to function. The problem I am facing is that every time I make a change to an application I need to stop and then start tomcat which takes about 10 minutes to load all the applications. This is very time consuming and frustrating. Is this how people usually develop in java? In IIS when I redeploy an app, only its worker process (application pool) needs to be restarted. Thus I do not need to reload all applications when developing in IIS. Is there a similar concept in tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only change one WAR file, you could hot-deploy it via the [Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)  This is probably the simplest from a usability standpoint.  Simply login to the tomcat manager for your running instance `(http://[host]:[port]/manager/[command]?[parameters])` From there you can deploy, stop, start, undeploy (delete) and reload.  Note that your server needs to enable access to the manager and have a user you can login as to perform the admin functions.

The other option is to use Eclipse to run the tomcat instance.  You will need to change the server properties to "Automatically publish when resources change"  found under the publishing tab.  You'll also need to disable Auto-Reload on the tomcat plugin module view.  [M K Yong](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/) has a nice little tutorial for this if you need pictures.